# Xen 64bit Install

Tags: linux, xen

Trying to install Xen on my 64bit O/S (Centos 5).

Using this guideline: 
http://www.howtoforge.org/paravirtualization-with-xen-on-centos-5.3-x86_64

```
[root@server ~]# virt-install
What is the name of your virtual machine? vm01
How much RAM should be allocated (in megabytes)? 256
What would you like to use as the disk (file path)? /vm/vm01.img
How large would you like the disk (/vm/vm01.img) to be (in gigabytes)? 4
Disk /vm/vm01.img is already in use by another guest!
Do you really want to use the disk (yes or no)? yes
Would you like to enable graphics support? (yes or no) no
What is the install location? http://wftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux.../5.3/os/x86_64


Starting install...
Retrieving file CentOS... | 1.5 MB 00:05
Retrieving file vmlinuz... | 1.9 MB 00:05
Retrieving file initrd.img... | 6.3 MB 00:07
ERROR: Domain named vm01 already exists!
[root@server ~]# rm -f /vm/vm01.img
[root@server ~]# xm destroy vm01
Error: Domain 'vm01' does not exist.
Usage: xm destroy <Domain>

Terminate a domain immediately.

[root@server ~]# xm list
Name ID Mem(MiB) VCPUs State Time(s)
Domain-0 0 1744 2 r----- 29.5
```

I created a new one called vm02

But I'm stuck at the configure tcp/ip screen. The "sending request for IP..." disappears and shows the default configure tcp/ip screen again.

```
[root@server ~]# /sbin/ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: peth0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 100
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop qlen 1000
link/ether 00:11:43:fd:97:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop
link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: vif0.0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
link/ether 00:11:43:fd:97:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: vif0.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: vif0.2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: veth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: vif0.3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: veth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
14: vif0.4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: veth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: xenbr0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
18: vif2.0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 32
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Screenshot 
http://tinypic.com/r/260x3k3/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first error, try looking in /etc/xen for a file called 'vm01' and deleting it, also, try running 'virsh' and then 'list --all' to find the "offending domain". You can the use "undefine " to remove it.

As for the second problem, are you sure you have a DHCP server on the network? Are you sure you've connected your domain to a public bridge (xenbr0)? You can use the "-b BRIDGE" switch of virt-install to make sure you have.

If you do not have a DHCP server, you can pass the installer static IP configuration by adding the following to virt-install:

```
-x "ip=<ip address> gateway=<gateway> subnet=<subnet>"
```

Comment: I did not manually install DHCP. All I did was have Centos 5 64bit installed and I installed Xen using that guideline.

Please explain what you mean by "you can pass the installer static IP configuration by adding the following to virt-install:"

For example, the /29 subnet assigned to my server is xxx.xxx.64.170 - 174 (usable). I did not assign this subnet in the networking or such, please explain.

Comment: As i understand you're installing on a hosted server, and you must likely don't have a DHCP server. The "-x" option allows you to pass a static ip to the installer so it will not look for an IP over DHCP, but statically configure you interface with the supplied IP.
To use the -x option run:
virt-install -x "...." and just supply the rest of the options interactively.

Comment: Ok, the install command should look like this? With or without quotes anyway?

virt-install -x "ip=xxx.xxx.64.170 gateway=xxx.xxx.64.169 subnet=255.255.255.248"

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Thanks, now got a new problem. The download link from that guide was not working, so I found a mirror which is giving me an error still even though the path is right and the img file is there.

Unable to retrieve 
http://centos.digitalson.com//centos/5/os/x86_64/images/minstg2.img.

But the file is there, same path:
http://centos.digitalson.com/centos/5/os/x86_64/images/

http://i42.tinypic.com/wu5uvq.png

Comment: BTW, this is my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0  content

DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.64.170
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet

Comment: Did you add a DNS server?
using 64.16.220.161 (centos.digitalson.com ip) as the web site name or adding "dns=<comma seperated list>" to your virt-install -x command

Comment: I tried this:

virt-install -x "ip=xxx.xxx.64.170 gateway=xxx.xxx.64.169 subnet=255.255.255.248 dns=64.16.220.161"

What is the name of your virtual machine? vm22
 How much RAM should be allocated (in megabytes)? 256
 What would you like to use as the disk (file path)? /vm/vm22.img
 How large would you like the disk (/vm/vm22.img) to be (in gigabytes)? 4
 Would you like to enable graphics support? (yes or no) no
 What is the install location? http://centos.digitalson.com/centos/5/os/x86_64

Then, on the conf tcp/ip screen, I get blank screen

http://tinypic.com/r/10hitmo/5

Comment: It's most likely downloading the install image from the location you specified, give it some time

Comment: Still not working

http://tinypic.com/r/30kd6c9/5

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I am in the same boat.

Currently, able to start the domain it downloads the stuff and fails to go to the stage2 of installations due to inability to access the stage2.img file even when the path is right.Welcome to CentOS

```
          +-----------------+ HTTP Setup +------------------+              
          |                                                 |              
          | Please enter the following information:         |              
          |                                                 |              
          |     o the name or IP number of your Web server  |              
          |     o the directory on that server containing   |              
          |       CentOS for your architecture              |              
          |                                                 |              
          |   Web site name:    mirror.centos.org_______    |              
          |   CentOS directory: /centos/5/os/x86_64_____    |              
          |                                                 |              
          |         +----+                 +------+         |              
          |         | OK |                 | Back |         |              
          |         +----+                 +------+         |              
          |                                                 |              
          |                                                 |              
          +-------------------------------------------------+          

                 +-------------+ Error +-------------+                     
                 |                                   |                     
                 | Unable to retrieve                |                     
                 | http://mirror.centos.org//centos
```

|
                     | /5/os/x86_64/images/stage2.img.   |
                     |                                   |
                     |              +----+               |
                     |              | OK |               |
                     |              +----+               |
                     |                                   |
                     |                                   |
                     +-----------------------------------+

System is able to download the stuff and the installation stops right there.
I checked the URL and there seems to be no problem.

Regards
Rajan